# rvm don't use latest jruby version (1.7.12)

Tags: rvm, jruby

I have jruby 1.7.4 installed, and I want install also version 1.7.12, and use it when I run:

```
rvm use jruby
```

I performed the following steps:

```
rvm get latest
rvm install jruby 1.7.12
```

When I run:

```
rvm list known
```

I get also: jruby[-1.7.12]

But when I execute:

```
rvm use jruby
```

or

```
rvm install jruby
```

It tries to use and install jruby version 1.7.4

What should I do to make 'rvm use jruby' use version 1.7.12 without specifying explicitly:

`rvm use jruby 1.7.12` ?

Comment: I'd've advised `rvm get stable` but for the fact that `rvm list known` reports the latest version correctly. No clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why **rvm use** is not working

You can add **.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.12/bin** to your **$PATH** (try editing .bashrc for linux, .bash_profile for osX), restart console and run '**jruby -v**'. It should be 1.7.12.

Hope that solves your problem.